# API Pagination in Dropwizard

Tags: java, jersey, dropwizard

I am using Dropwizard to develop a webservice. Now I need to enable pagination feature for my service but I dont know how to go about it. I kindly need help to implement pagination.

Comment: Are you talking about adding a number of result and start param, just triggering a `LIMIT 10, 10` in SQL for example ?

Comment: Yes, but I also want the links to be added to the headers.

Comment: You have to generate it by hands I think.

Answer (score 4):

Jerseys' [Declarative Hyperlinking](https://jersey.github.io/documentation/latest/user-guide.html#declarative-linking) feature comes very handy to implement pagination in a DropWizard application. I put together a simple [implementation](https://github.com/aruld/dropwizard-pagination) that shows pagination using link headers. The view showcases basic pagination, but you get the point.

I adapted Jersey's built-in [example](https://github.com/jersey/jersey/tree/master/examples/declarative-linking) for this implementation. It supports both XML and JSON via content negotiation using "Accept" header.

[image: DropWizard Bootstrap Pagination]
[image: Link Header in Response]

Comment: Thanks for that, Arul - this is the first thing I came upon when starting to search for this and it is exactly what I was looking for!